# create dynamically some sliders / sliders don't move

Tags: ios, objective-c

i want to create dynamically some sliders

With my  IBAction create1Slider, i can move my slider

***With my  IBAction create10Sliders, i can't move my slider***

what is wrong?

```
- (IBAction) create1Slider:(id)sender {
    UISlider *slider = [[[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 150, 100, 100)] autorelease];
    slider.minimumValue = 1;
    slider.maximumValue = 255;
    slider.continuous = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:slider];
    }
```

//////////////////////////

```
- (IBAction) create10Sliders:(id)sender {
for(int i=0; i< 10
; i++)
{

    UISlider *slider = [[[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100+i*80)] autorelease];
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    slider.minimumValue = 1;
    slider.maximumValue = 255;
    slider.continuous = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:slider];
    //[slider release];

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You ended up by creating all the ten sliders placed on each other, due to creatin on the same co-ordinates**.

```
UISlider *slider = [[[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100+i*80)] autorelease];
```

You kept same `x` and `y` as 50 and 50. And `height` as 100 and changed `width` by 100+i*80.

As:

```
CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)
```

You need to to change `y` if you want them vertically placed.

Comment: @user2207904: Then you may accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all 10 sliders are being created overlapping one another, at the same origin point (50,50). You need their origin points (esp. the y value) to differ.

The reason you can't see that fact is that most of the background of a slider is transparent. So you have these huge increasing rectangles overlapping, with the biggest covering all the others; but all you *see* is the track-and-thumb. To visualise the issue, give each slider a background color. Then the problem will be dead obvious.